# Geting the last modified date and time of a microsoft planner task using APIs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I'm triying to get last modified date of every task of my company plan (as is shown on top of task details screen, e.g. "Last changes moments ago by you").

I read PlannerTaskDetails and plannerExternalReferences documentation and it says that "lastModifiedDateTime" can be retrieved as an attribute included in the node "references" of task's "details".

However, in every task of my plan, "references" array is empty, even in a modified task.

How can I get lastModifiedDateTime?